# Which GUI framework is used by the "Spybot Search & Destroy" application?

Tags: c++

I want to replicate the look and feel of Spybot Search & Destroy in my own applications. Is there a publicly-available framework, toolkit, or library to aid in this task?

Comment: Are you referring to "SpyBoy - Search and Destroy"?

Comment: Let's proceed under that assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAICR it's written in Delphi. With C++ Builder you can use Delphi libraries from C++.

Answer (score 1):

In this blog post, they mention that they use Delphi:

http://www.safer-networking.org/en/news/2005-06-22.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an MFC application to me.

http://www.safer-networking.org/de/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Most of the GUI framworks that use native operating system widgets will allow you to produce something similar.

Here are 2 GUI Frameworks that uses the native widgets of the OS.

- MFC
- wxWidgets